# "Method not found" error in XAML designer

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I want my user control to display data when I am viewing it in the WPF designer in Visual Studio.

The ViewModel does not have a default constructor, so I wrote my own static `TestData` class to construct the model and all of its dependencies.

```
public static class TestData
{
    public static ELabelViewModel ELabelViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return new ELabelViewModel
            (
                new ControlPanelGridLine(TestData.ELabel),
                new SerialPortFactoryImpl(),
                new Repository(),
                new PriceLabelGenerator(TestData.IPriceLabelViewModelFactory)
            );
        }
    }

    // Other static getter methods
```

This all compiles with no problems. However, problems start when I add this in the XAML:

```
   d:DataContext="{x:Static local:TestData.ELabelViewModel}"
```

The XAML editor puts a curly blue line under my `d:DataContext` attribute, and in the error list I see:

> Error 7   Method not found: 'Void
>   ELabel.Manager.ViewModels.ELabelViewModel..ctor(ELabel.Manager.ViewModels.ControlPanelGridLine,
>   ELabel.Control.ISerialPortFactory, ELabel.Data.IRepository,
>   ELabel.ImageGeneration.IPriceLabelGenerator)'.

My interpretation of this is that it is finding the `TestData` class, and also finding the `TestData.ELabelViewModel` property. It just cannot resolve the constructor that is being called inside the getter.

Why can it not find the `ELabelViewModel` constructor? To confirm my code was OK, I made this test view model the actual data context by using `DataContext=` instead of `d:DataContext=`. In this case I opened the application and confirmed that, at runtime, all works as expected: `TestData.ELabelViewModel` was invoked, the code insider the getter function ran, and it used this view model. It's just the designer that is failing to run the code.

The `ELabelViewModel` class is in a separate assembly called `ELabel.Manager.ViewModels`. Is the editor failing to fully load this assembly?

**Later Edit**

I tried moving this `TestData` class to the `ELabel.Manager.ViewModels` assembly (the same assembly that the constructor resides in). Sure enough, it now works fine, and I can see test data when viewing the control in the editor. Curious.

I've double-checked that the `ELabelViewModel` class and the constructor are public (Which of course it is, otherwise I never would have been able to build the application).

Comment: Maybe it was simply a matter of assembly references, your static class was simply unknown and there for,  might have cause the void return.

Comment: Lemme guess--gives an error in the designer, but it compiles and runs fine?  The designer does that kind of crap all the time.  Just ignore it.  Hopefully it'll be a bit more reliable in '15.

Answer (score 1):

I implement all my viewmodel classes like this:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApp.Views.MainView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyApp.ViewModel"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" Height="607" Width="616">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:TestData/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
```